# How to map widget's position to secondary monitor screen?

Tags: qt

I need the position of a widget relativ to the screen it is on.
Right now I only can figure out the screen and the resolution of that screen via `QDesktopWidget.screen(number).size()`. And of course the global position. But how to get the position on the single screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert from a *global* position to a *screen* position you can use the following function:

```
QPoint globalToScreen(QPoint pt)
{
  return pt - QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry(pt).topLeft();
}
```

This works by getting the geometry (position and size) of the screen the point is on, then calculating the difference between the screen's position and the point.